# MySQL query breaks on certain WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that only crashes on one certain where clause, it says the `table has crashed and needs to be repaired`.

This query works:

```
SELECT
    DirectionId
FROM
    Messages
WHERE
    CustomField1 = 56 AND DirectionId = 1
```

This one does not

```
SELECT
    DirectionId
FROM
    Messages
WHERE
    CustomField1 = 209 AND DirectionId = 1
```

But if I do this it works:

```
SELECT
    DirectionId
FROM
    Messages
WHERE
    CustomField1 = 209
```

Or this it also works

```
SELECT
    DirectionId
FROM
    Messages
WHERE
    DirectionId = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Messages` to your question. Seems like you have an index `KEY(CustomField1, DirectionId)` (or similar) which is broken and needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: for a simple try, do `REPAIR TABLE Messages` on the MySQL CLI.

Comment: can u show the table sttructure?

Comment: Consider contacting your host.

Comment: Did you try repairing the table?

Comment: @Kaii please add your comment as a answer so I can accept it

Comment: moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the MySQL internal cleanup routines to repair your INDEXes:

Type this on the MySQL CLI:

```
REPAIR TABLE Messages
```